# React Native Js - TypeError: l.map is not function

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, pie-chart

i m new on Js and React,for my semester 2, I have to make an application of Macronutrient.

The problem is that I would like to use a Piechart with the values of my state.

for pie chart a isued react-native-chart-kit

u can see on this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit

I tried

Piechart

```
<PieChart
                                        width={screenWidth}
                                        data={{
                                            datasets: [{
                                                data: [
                                                    { name: 'Glucide', nb:this.state.glucide, color: '#F00', legendFontColor: '#F00', legendFontSize: 15 },
                                                    { name: 'Proteine', nb: this.state.protaine, color: '#4250f4', legendFontColor: '#4250f4', legendFontSize: 15 },
                                                    { name: 'Lipide', nb: this.state.lipide, color: '#04e578', legendFontColor: '#04e578', legendFontSize: 15 },
                                                ]
                                            }]
                                        }}
                                        height={220}
                                        accessor="nb"
                                        chartConfig={chartConfig}
                                        backgroundColor="transparent"
                                        absolute/>
```

and i get TypeError: l.map is not a function. (In'l.map(c)','l.map' is undefined

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 1):

l.map is not function, this error typically cause by the variable call .map() is not an array.

In this case, you should pass data array direct to data

```
const data = [
        { name: 'Glucide', nb:this.state.glucide, color: '#F00', legendFontColor: '#F00', legendFontSize: 15 },
        { name: 'Proteine', nb: this.state.protaine, color: '#4250f4', legendFontColor: '#4250f4', legendFontSize: 15 },
        { name: 'Lipide', nb: this.state.lipide, color: '#04e578', legendFontColor: '#04e578', legendFontSize: 15 } 
      ]

<PieChart
      width={screenWidth}
      data={data}
      height={220}
      accessor="nb"
      chartConfig={chartConfig}
      backgroundColor="transparent"
      absolute 
/>
```

Comment: Ok, but if i try this, in const data we can't acces of state.glucide